# Rails select from database table by multiple join throug other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, select

I have model Category (categories of Images)

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, foreign_key: 'category_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subscriptions, foreign_key: "category_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subscribed_users, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user
end
```

Model Category has many subscribtions and subscribed users

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, foreign_key: 'user_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, foreign_key: 'user_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_images, :through => :likes, :source => :images
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :commented_images, :through => :comments, :source => :images
  has_many :subscriptions, foreign_key: 'user_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subscribed_categories, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :categories
end
```

Also I have model Image

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :likes, foreign_key: "image_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liking_users, :through => :likes, :source => :user
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: "image_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :commenting_users, :through => :comments, :source => :user
end
```

which has many likes and comments (comments and likes to Image, not to categories of image)

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :image
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :image_id, presence: true
end
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :image
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :image_id, presence: true
end
```

I need to select from database 5 most popular categories.
The most popular category is category which has highest count of likes, comments and images at the same time.

I made one query, which select all images, that has the highest count of likes and comments:

```
@top_images = Image.left_outer_joins(:likes).distinct.select('images.*, COUNT(likes.*) AS likes_count').left_outer_joins(:comments).distinct.select('images.*, COUNT(comments.*) AS comments_count').group(
        'images.id').order("likes_count DESC").order("comments_count DESC")
```

Also I make query which select categories, which has more images:

```
@top_categories_img_count = Category.left_outer_joins(:images).distinct.select('categories.*, COUNT(images.*) AS images_count').group(
        'categories.id').order("images_count DESC")
```

But I have no idea how to select all categories which have highest count of images, likes and comments